# can't stat file more than once?

Tags: ffmpeg, cifs, stat, snap

So I've got a bizarre error that occurs when I use `ffmpeg.ffprobe` on an MP4 file that is hosted my NAS.

When I login to a shell and switch to any directory on my network storage that contains a MP4 file, and then I run `ffmpeg.ffprobe` on that file, I can run that command successfully exactly once per file.  The first time, I get the expected output.  Then, if I run it again, it'll say

```
cannot stat path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

If there are other MP4 files in the directory, those will work once as well.  If I login with a new shell and then perform the same command in the new shell, it will work in that shell once.

I can actually stat the file, even after I receive the error.

These problems do not occur if I copy the files to a local directory and perform the same operations.

Can anyone tell me why an operation like this would succeed once, then fail?  And how I can fix it?  Let me know what other info I can post that would be helpful.

EDIT:  So `ffmpeg.ffprobe` is the executable provided by my snap installation.  I uninstalled and reinstalled that, and made sure it had the "removable media" permission enabled.  Alternatively, if I run just the `ffprobe` executable, which is provided by `apt`, none of these problems occur.  I've temporarily solved my problem by using `ffprobe`, but I still haven't solved the issue.

```
$snap connections ffmpeg
Interface         Plug                     Slot              Notes
alsa              ffmpeg:alsa              -                 -
audio-playback    ffmpeg:audio-playback    :audio-playback   -
audio-record      ffmpeg:audio-record      -                 -
camera            ffmpeg:camera            -                 -
desktop           ffmpeg:desktop           :desktop          -
hardware-observe  ffmpeg:hardware-observe  -                 -
home              ffmpeg:home              :home             -
network           ffmpeg:network           :network          -
network-bind      ffmpeg:network-bind      :network-bind     -
opengl            ffmpeg:opengl            :opengl           -
optical-drive     ffmpeg:optical-drive     :optical-drive    -
pulseaudio        ffmpeg:pulseaudio        :pulseaudio       -
removable-media   ffmpeg:removable-media   :removable-media  manual
wayland           ffmpeg:wayland           :wayland          -
x11               ffmpeg:x11               :x11              -
```

Example:

```
$ ffmpeg.ffprobe file.mp4 
ffprobe version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-cuda --enable-cuda-sdk --enable-cuvid --enable-libdrm --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnpp --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2016-09-24T00:49:20.000000Z
    com.android.version: 6.0.1
  Duration: 00:13:36.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17260 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 16999 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-09-24T00:49:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-09-24T00:49:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle

$ ffmpeg.ffprobe file.mp4 
cannot stat path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

here the relevant mount point:

```
//192.168.1.103/Volume_1 on /media/rothloup/Volume_1 type cifs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=none,cache=strict,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=192.168.1.103,soft,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,user=rothloup)
```

output of ls -al and stat:

```
$ ls -al
total 3444736
drwxrwxrwx 2 rothloup rothloup          0 Sep 19 20:20 .
drwxrwxrwx 7 rothloup rothloup          0 Feb  4  2019 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 rothloup rothloup 1761256156 Dec  5  2016 2016-09-23_204920.mp4
-rw-rw-rw- 1 rothloup rothloup 1761256156 Sep 19 20:24 file.mp4

$ stat file.mp4 
  File: file.mp4
  Size: 1761256156      Blocks: 3444736    IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Device: 36h/54d Inode: 49512449    Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: ( 1000/rothloup)   Gid: ( 1000/rothloup)
Access: 2021-09-19 21:36:10.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2021-09-19 20:24:39.000000000 -0400
Change: 2021-09-19 20:24:39.000000000 -0400
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Does it also happens if you try `ffprobe` with the full path to the mp4 file? I would try mounting the share with the `noserverino` option, though that is just a hunch ;-)

Comment: @ktzap:  I tried it with a full path, as well as several intermediate paths, and all of them behave the same way.  I'll try the noserverino option tomorrow.

Comment: @ktzap  I tried the "noserverino" option.  It had no effect when I re-mounted the volume.  I'm still stumped.